# Downloading files in chunks in python?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-requests, http-headers, download-manager

I am writing a simple synchronous download manager which downloads a video file in 10 sections. I am using `requests` to get content-length from headers. Using this I am breaking and downloading files in 10; byte chunks and then merging them to form a complete video. The code below suppose to work this way but the end merged file only works for seconds and after that it gets corrupted. What is wrong in my code?

```
import requests
import os

def intervals(parts, duration):
    part_duration = duration // parts
    return [(i * part_duration, (i + 1) * part_duration) for i in range(parts)]

home = os.path.expanduser("~")
if not os.path.exists(home+'/Desktop/temp'):
    os.makedirs(home+'/Desktop/temp')

PATH = home+"/Desktop/temp/tmp.mp4"

example_file_url = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4"


req = requests.head(example_file_url)

size = int(req.headers['Content-Length'])

content_section = 10

section_intervals = intervals(content_section,size)


with  open(PATH, "wb") as file:
    for i,(start,end) in enumerate(section_intervals):
        headers = {"Range": "bytes="+str(start)+"-"+str(end)}
        print(headers)
        r = requests.get(example_file_url, headers=headers)
        file.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

Your ranges are wrong because the interval specified by a `Range` header gives the first and the last offset, e.g. `bytes=0-10` means 11 bytes from 0 to 10 (unlike how slices work in python), so `bytes=0-10` and `bytes=10-20` are overlapping ranges.  For example, you would need `bytes=0-9` followed by `bytes=10-19` instead.

See the example in this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests):

> header requesting the first 1024 bytes ... `Range: bytes=0-1023`

(whereas `[0:1023]` in a python slice would be length 1023).

Where you say that it "works for seconds and after that gets corrupted", I assume that you mean that it is valid for the first few seconds of decoded MP4 output. The point where it breaks will be the end of the first downloaded part, where the final byte of the first part is duplicated at the start of the second part.

Another problem is that your total length is wrong because you do integer division by `parts` and then by the time that you multiply it up again, you have lost the final fractional part.

### The fix

Change your `intervals` function to this, and it works:

```
import math

def intervals(parts, duration):
    part_duration = math.ceil(duration / parts)
    return [(start, min(start + part_duration - 1, duration - 1)) 
             for start in range(0, duration, part_duration)]
```

### Inspecting the ranges

Inserting print statements:

```
print("Size = ", size)
print(section_intervals)
```

now gives:

```
Size =  9840497
[(0, 984049), (984050, 1968099), (1968100, 2952149), (2952150, 3936199), (3936200, 4920249), (4920250, 5904299), (5904300, 6888349), (6888350, 7872399), (7872400, 8856449), (8856450, 9840496)]
```

whereas using your original `intervals` function, it gives:

```
Size =  9840497
[(0, 984049), (984049, 1968098), (1968098, 2952147), (2952147, 3936196), (3936196, 4920245), (4920245, 5904294), (5904294, 6888343), (6888343, 7872392), (7872392, 8856441), (8856441, 9840490)]
```

Note the overlapping ranges and the bytes missing from the end.

### Verifying output using md5sum

We can verify the download at the end by calculating a checksum.  In this example, I use `md5sum` from the Linux command line (although `cksum` would work also, as there is no need for cryptographic checksum for this purpose).

I called the output `myoutput`.

```
$ md5sum myoutput
10c918b1d01aea85864ee65d9e0c2305  myoutput
```

Now I also download a copy directly with `wget <url>` and see that it has the same checksum.

```
$ wget https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4
--2020-07-21 08:26:52--  https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4

$ md5sum file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4 
10c918b1d01aea85864ee65d9e0c2305  file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4
```